# What is wrong with my Javascript promise implementation?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I’m trying to build my own Promise to improve my understanding of Promise in javascript. I’m currently stuck at the `.then` method and I’d like to ask:
In the documentation for `.then` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then , it says that the `then` method returns a Promise. I’m having difficulties writing this because it seem like `this.result` is `undefined`. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
class LitePromise {
  constructor(fn) {
    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError("Promises have to be functions");
    }
    this.fn = fn;
    this.state = PENDING;
    this.result = null;
    const resolveCallback = this.resolve.bind(this);
    const rejectCallback = this.reject.bind(this);
    try {
      fn(resolveCallback, rejectCallback);
    } catch (err) {
      this.reject(err);
    }
  }

  resolve(arg) {
    console.log(arg, "arg");
    this.result = arg;
    this.state = RESOLVED;
  }

  reject() {
    this.state = REJECTED;
  }

  // make an instance of this promise
  then(callback) {
    const tinyPromise = new LitePromise(this.fn);
    console.log(callback, "callback");
    try {
      return tinyPromise.resolve(callback(this.result));
    } catch {
      return tinyPromise.reject(callback(this.result));
    }
  }
}

console.log("------------------");
const yaypromise = new LitePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("1. running");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("2. resolving");
    resolve("yay");
  }, 100);
}).then((result) => {
  console.log("3. evaluating");
  if (result !== "yay") {
    console.log("Is not working yet");
    return;
  }
  console.log("SUCCESS!", result);
});
```

Comment: There are all sorts of things wrong here, `.then()` can be passed two callbacks.  You don't have a `.catch()` method.  Inside of `.then()`, you would not use the executor callback function again when you construct a new promise.  That is called once and only once when the original promise is created.  `reject()` takes a reason.

Comment: Also don't catch errors when you call the executor (called `fn` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

I think the core issue here is the following. `then()` typically gets processed in 2 different ways:

1. The promise is pending. Store the callback(s) passed to `then()` and call those callbacks when the promise gets resolved *later*.
2. The promise has a result (it resolved or rejected), in which case we'll call the callback passed to then as soon as possible.

You're never handling case 1, so if the promise resolves *after* `then()` gets called, it won't work.

In addition, the sub promise you *return* from `then()` should itself resolve one the *result* of the callback passed to `then()` completes.

If this sounds super confusing, it's because it's hard =) I would recommend to try and get your logic right first for just dealing with the callbacks in `.then()`, and don't return anything from `.then()` *yet*.

I also made my own promise for the same reason. It's pretty minimal, maybe it's helpful:

https://github.com/evert/promise-demo/blob/master/src/my-promise.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program we expect to work with our `promise`; note the lowercase `p` -

```js
const delay = ms =>
  new promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  
const roll = n =>
{ console.log("rolling...")
  return delay(1000)
    .then(_ => Math.ceil(Math.random() * n))
    .then(x => { console.log(x); return x })
}

const main = _ =>
  roll(20).then(x =>
    roll(20).then(y =>
      roll(20).then(z =>
        { console.log("three rolls:", x, y, z)
          return [x,y,z]
        }
      )
    )
  )

main()
  .then(([x,y,z]) => x + y + z)
  .then(sum => console.log("sum:", sum))
  .catch(console.error)
```

```
rolling...
12
rolling...
18
rolling...
15
three rolls: 12 18 15
sum: 45
```

As others commented there is a lot to fix in your code. But don't feel bad as Promise is not particularly easy to implement. Here's my first sketch of `promise`. Note `value`, `resolved`, `rejected` are parameters of the constructor but they should be made private. This can be done using a variety of techniques, but for sake of simplicity I left it this way for now. The caller is only intended to pass the first argument, `exec` -

```js
class promise
{ constructor(exec, value, resolved = false, rejected = false)
  { this.value = value
    this.resolved = resolved
    this.rejected = rejected
    this.callback = []
    if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    exec(x => this.resolve(x), e => this.reject(e))
  }
  
  resolve(value)
  { if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    let p = promise.resolve(value)
    for (const [ifResolved, ifRejected] of this.callback)
      p = p.then(ifResolved, ifRejected)
    Object.assign(this, p)
  }
  
  reject(value)
  { if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    let p = promise.reject(value)
    for (const [ifResolved, ifRejected] of this.callback)
      p = p.then(ifResolved, ifRejected)
    Object.assign(this, p)
  }
  
  then(ifResolved, ifRejected = promise.reject)
  { if (this.resolved)
    { try
      { return promise.resolve(ifResolved(this.value)) }
      catch (err)
      { return promise.reject(err) }
    }
    else if (this.rejected)
    { try
      { return promise.resolve(ifRejected(this.value)) }
      catch (err)
      { return promise.reject(err) }
    }
    else
    { this.callback.push([ifResolved, ifRejected])
      return this
    }
  }
  
  catch(ifRejected)
  { return this.then(value => value, ifRejected) }
  
  static resolve(value)
  { return (value instanceof promise)
      ? value
      : new promise(_ => {}, value, true, false)
  }
  
  static reject(value)
  { return (value instanceof promise)
      ? value
      : new promise(_ => {}, value, false, true)
  }
}
```

Like Promise, only `p.then`, `p.catch` should be available on `promise` objects. We should prevent the user from calling `p.resolve` or `p.reject` directly, but for now it makes it easy to see how things work. The class functions `promise.resolve` and `promise.reject` are analogous to `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject`.

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
class promise
{ constructor(exec, value, resolved = false, rejected = false)
  { this.value = value
    this.resolved = resolved
    this.rejected = rejected
    this.callback = []
    if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    exec(x => this.resolve(x), e => this.reject(e))
  }
  
  resolve(value)
  { if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    let p = promise.resolve(value)
    for (const [ifResolved, ifRejected] of this.callback)
      p = p.then(ifResolved, ifRejected)
    Object.assign(this, p)
  }
  
  reject(value)
  { if (this.resolved || this.rejected) return
    let p = promise.reject(value)
    for (const [ifResolved, ifRejected] of this.callback)
      p = p.then(ifResolved, ifRejected)
    Object.assign(this, p)
  }
  
  then(ifResolved, ifRejected = promise.reject)
  { if (this.resolved)
    { try
      { return promise.resolve(ifResolved(this.value)) }
      catch (err)
      { return promise.reject(err) }
    }
    else if (this.rejected)
    { try
      { return promise.resolve(ifRejected(this.value)) }
      catch (err)
      { return promise.reject(err) }
    }
    else
    { this.callback.push([ifResolved, ifRejected])
      return this
    }
  }
  
  catch(ifRejected)
  { return this.then(value => value, ifRejected) }
  
  static resolve(value)
  { return (value instanceof promise)
      ? value
      : new promise(_ => {}, value, true, false)
  }
  
  static reject(value)
  { return (value instanceof promise)
      ? value
      : new promise(_ => {}, value, false, true)
  }
}

const delay = ms =>
  new promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  
const roll = n =>
{ console.log("rolling...")
  return delay(1000)
    .then(_ => Math.ceil(Math.random() * n))
    .then(x => { console.log(x); return x })
}

const main = _ =>
  roll(20).then(x =>
    roll(20).then(y =>
      roll(20).then(z =>
        { console.log("three rolls:", x, y, z)
          return [x,y,z]
        }
      )
    )
  )

main()
  .then(([x,y,z]) => x + y + z)
  .then(sum => console.log("sum:", sum))
  .catch(console.error)
```

I will come back tomorrow to add an example that demonstrates errors and answer any questions if you have them.